# Saving a new object with foreignkey - but listing all its attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Saving a new object that has a foreign key is no problem using Django rest frame work as is. But I needed to expose a related models attributes and not just its pk for an app listing its details. Now I have a problem posting a new object, because the related field is not just a PK anymore, but an object.

This is how it looks now:

```
[  
{  
    "id":1,
    "hit":true,
    "mis":false,
    "lat":null,
    "lon":null,
    "altitude":null,
    "gps_accuracy":"",
    "site":{  
        "id":1,
        "name":"Kiepersol 8",
        "lat":null,
        "lon":null,
        "altitude":null,
        "gps_accuracy":"",
        "user":1
    },
    "species":{  
        "id":1,
        "name":"Panicum maximum",
        "grazing_value":"h",
        "ecological_succesional_value":"c",
        "response_to_grazing_impact":"D"
    }
}
]
```

I want to save like this:

```
hit:false, mis:true, species:2, site: 1
```

This is my serializers:

```
class SpeciesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Species

class PointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Point
        depth = 1

class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    points = PointSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = SurveySite
```

Just to be clear, I need to show all those attributes of the related models for listing on another app. But its a problem when creating a new point object.

*I guess I basically what to have different DEPTHS for when doing a GET as to a POST, so the POST is flat.*

I guess I can have a seperate serializer for saving but Im sure htat is not the way!

Comment: can u tell show me your whole models ? ur big json is from what serializer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override your `create` method and get related object data, create them and assign them. Supose you have `DadSerializer` and it has `child` elements and you want to show them and allow `dad` instance creation using `DadSerializer`.

```
class DadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    childs = ChildSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Dad
        depth = 1

    def create(self,validated_data):
         childs_data = validated_data["childs"]


         del(validated_data["childs"])
         dad = Dad.objects.create(**validated_data)
         new_childs = []
         for data in childs_data:
              child = Child.objects.create(**data)
              new_childs.append(child)

         #clear previous childs if you dont want stack them
         dad.childs.clear()
         dad.childs.add(new_childs)
         dad.save()
         return dad
```